# some help on the following perl script

Tags: perl, merge, concatenation

Need help in merging/concatenating /combining /binding etc

1. I have several ascii files each defining one variable which I have converted to a single column array

I have such columnised data for many variables ,so I need to perform a column bind like `R` does and make it one single file.

I can do the same in `R` but there are too many files. Being able to do it with one single code will help save a lot of time.

Using the following code ,new  to perl and need help with this.

```
@filenames = ("file1.txt","file2.txt");
open F2, ">file_combined.txt" or die;
for($j = 0; $j< scalar @filenames;$j++){
    open F1, $filenames[$j] or die;
    for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){$line=<F1>;}
    while($line=<F1>){
        chomp $line;
        @spl = split '\s+', $line;
        for($i=0;$i<scalar @spl;$i++){
            print F2 "$spl[$i]\n";
            paste "file_bio1.txt","file_bio2.txt"> file_combined.txt;
        }
    }
    close F1;
}
```

Input files here are Ascii text files of a raster.They look like this

```
32 12 34 21 32 21 22 23 
12 21 32 43 21 32 21 12
```

The above mentioned code without the paste syntax converts these files into a single column

```
32 
12 
34  
21 
32 
21 
22 
23
12 
21
32 
43 
21  
32 
21 
12 


The output should look like this
12  21  32
32  23  23
32  21  32
12  34  12
43  32  32
32  23  23
32  34  21
21  32  23
```

Each column represents a different ascii file.
I need around 15 such ascii files into one dataframe.I can do the same in R but it consumes a lot of time as the number of files and regions of interest are too many and the files are a bit large too.

Comment: Assuming you are in a *nix environment how about using `join`?  Also, where do file_bio1.txt and file_bio2.txt come from?  Are you trying to call `paste` without backticks as well?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do?

Comment: No that was a typing error,I meant to write file1.txt and so on...when I did try the code ,it gives me an error,cant find string terminator anywhere before EOF (line12).Will try out join

Comment: Please edit this; to show example input files, and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Let's step through what you have...

```
# files you want to open for reading..
@filenames = ("file1.txt","file2.txt");

# I would use the 3 arg lexical scoped open
# I think you want to open this for 'append' as well
# open($fh, ">>", "file_combined.txt") or die "cannot open";
open F2, ">file_combined.txt" or die;

# @filenames is best thought as a 'list'
# for my $file (@filenames) {
for($j = 0; $j< scalar @filenames;$j++){
    # see above example of 'open'
    # - $filenames[$j] + $file
    open F1, $filenames[$j] or die;

    # what are you trying to do here? You're overriding 
    # $line in the next 'while loop'
    for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){$line=<F1>;}
    # while(<$fh1>) {
    while($line=<F1>){
        chomp $line;
        # @spl is short for split? 
        # give '@spl' list a meaningful name
        @spl = split '\s+', $line;
        # again, @spl is a list...
        # for my $word (@spl) {
        for($i=0;$i<scalar @spl;$i++){
            # this whole block is a bit confusing. 
            # 'F2' is 'file_combined.txt'. Then you try and merge
            # ( and overwrite the file) with the paste afterwards...
            print F2 "$spl[$i]\n";
            # is this a 'system call'? 
            # Missing 'backticks' or 'system'
            paste "file_bio1.txt","file_bio2.txt"> file_combined.txt;
        }
    }
    # close $fh1
    close F1;
}
# I'm assuming there's a 'close F2' somewhere here..
```

It looks like you're trying to do this:

```
@filenames = ("file1.txt","file2.txt");
$oufile = "combined_text.txt";
`paste $filenames[0] $filenames[1] > $outfile`;
```

Comment: Yes exactly.Also these files(file1.text etc.) are  ascii files of gridded  raster data  so I  am trying to paste each file as one column at the same time converting these ascii files into a single column.